# Alternatives to low-cardinality columns (and pointless indexes) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, indexing, cardinality

So I have a mysql table for photos on my website. Every photo is tied to one of two sets of entities, so has two columns; nEntity1FK, nEntity2FK.

Exactly one of these columns is always non-zero in every row.  As such about 50% of the rows have "0" in nEntity1FK, and about 50% have "0" in nEntity2FK.

All well and good so far.  Until I add a `WHERE nEntity1FK=0` clause.  Things suddenly get pretty slow, even if I have a `LIMIT 0,50` to go with it.

I kinda understand why.  I get that low-cardinality indexes are bad and generally don't get used.  What's the alternative though?  The only thing I can think of is to keep all of my photo information in 2 separate tables instead of one (and have a view that joins them together for queries that need both).  This seems messy/hassle to me, is there a better option?

Thanks all.

Comment: column, index & table definition ? size of the table ?

Comment: What is the significance of the value 0? Do nEntity1FK and nEntity2FK actually have Foreign Keys?

Comment: Yes, they are foreign keys. I tend to use non-null columns for some reason... it was how I was taught and what I've stuck to since - my teacher may very well have been wrong.  I'm not convinced it would make any difference to the performance in this case if those 0s were NULLs instead, or do you think otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be using bitmap index, but as I know MySql does not support it.
Would it be possible to split the data into two tables? One where WHERE nEntity1FK=0 and one WHERE nEntity1FK=1

Comment: OK, good to learn about bitmap indexes, not come across those before.  As you say though, not available in mysql. I suppose I could split the data into two tables... why didn't I think of that?! ;-)

Comment: If you store records where nEntity1FK=0 in a spearated table, then you do not need to use index. If you google bitmax index+ mysql you might find some alternative solution.

Comment: I know Zoltan, I was joking... if you read my question you'll see I suggest this solution myself in the final paragraph :)